# how to set UIProgressview for one second?

Tags: iphone

How to iimplement uiprogressview for one minute using NStimer?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to increment the progress view at smaller intervals; say once a second or so.

Answer (score 0):

To animate the progress try this code: ( works with swift 5 )

```
UIProgressView.setProgress(3, animated: true)
```

// 3 refers to the duretion of progressing in seconds!